# Scanning in .NET using MODI (Microsoft Office Document Imaging)

Tags: .net, scanning, modi

I'm looking to leverage MS Office scanning functionality in my .NET application. Although I know that MODI COM objects can be accessed in .NET, I'm not sure how to make that. All I need is scanning to file and getting path of that file.

I don't need any OCR.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need scanning, not OCR, you don't need MODI. Just use TWAIN or WIA.

Here are two codeproject articles explaining more details:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/wiascriptingdotnet.aspx

This one talks a little bit about MODI

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/modi.aspx

Comment: The last one worked for a very old project of mine that had a MODI document dependency.